# гольфы - родительный падеж

Tags: орфоэпия

Как правильно будет родительный падеж множественного числа слова "гольфы":  "гольф" или "гольфов"?

Comment: Если это действительно родительный падеж. Я вот с удивлением обнаружил, что падежей в русском несколько больше чем 6, которые учатся в школе. И что на шкале действительно нет _граммов_, а не грамм. http://russian.stackexchange.com/a/405/5557

Comment: Alexey Burdin, не путайте. "Гольфами" пока ничего не меряют - и к ним представления о существовании дополнительного падежа (по Зализняку, другие авторы предпочитают называть "счетная форма") неприменимо. А таких квазипадежей всего семь. Т.е. вместе со школьными - 13. Ну это максимум из того, что насчитали. У других авторов - меньше.

Answer (score 1):

> ..."гольф" или "гольфов"?

Формы родительного падежа слова "гольфы" (и не только этого слова!) можно узнать, обратившись к электронным словарям, размещённым на портале Грамота.ру (http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=&all=x ):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]